# how to set textarea background transparent to show its contents on div placed behind/above it using either javascript or css only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a form with a text area whose value will the inner HTML of a div which I intend to place on top/below the text area and also be able to access the text area at the same time

my HTML with inline CSS and the javascript code to update the inner HTML of the div element is :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',document.querySelector(`#postbody`).focus())

function pcount() {
  // Word Count function for post
  document.querySelector(`#postbody`).focus()
  var i = document.querySelector(`#postbody`).value;
  document.querySelector('#postbodycontent').innerHTML = i;
  document.querySelector(`#postbody`).innerHTML = i
  document.querySelector(`#inputcountpost`).innerHTML = i.length;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid row">
    <div class="col-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <!-- Card profile details -->
            <div class="card-header p-1">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-auto my-auto me-3">
                  <a href="/profile/admin">
                    <img class="rounded-circle m-2 ms-2" src="https://www.dia.org/sites/default/files/No_Img_Avail.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" height="40px" width="40px">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <a href="/profile/admin" class="row">admin</a>
                  <figcaption class="small row blockquote-footer text-muted font-monospace">
                    Add New Post
                    <figcaption class="col-auto ms-auto me-3 small text-end text-muted font-monospace">
                      <span id="inputcountpost">0</span>/200
                    </figcaption>
                  </figcaption>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Card body -->
            <div class="card-body" style="padding:0px">
              <div class="form-control blockquote mb-0 text-warp text-break" id="postbodycontent" style="height:150px;box-shadow: none;border:0px none;position:absolute"></div>
              <textarea class="form-control blockquote mb-0 text-warp text-break" id="postbody" onfocus="pcount()" onkeydown="pcount()" maxlength="200" style="resize:none;height:150px;box-shadow: none;border:0px none;position:relative" autofocus>testing <b>innerhtml</b> activity</textarea>
            </div>

            <!-- Card Functionalities : bold, italics, etc and add post button-->
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
              <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-auto">

                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">

                </div>
                <div class="col-3 ms-auto">
                  <button class="btn form-control btn-primary" id="postsubmit" onclick="PostHandleForm(event)">
                      Add Post
                    </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

can someone please help out on how to position the div element on top of the text area and also be able to see the div as if it was a text area rendering its content in real-time

> **Note**:  I tried using content editable div it didn't help me out much and I need to be able to extract raw contents that are typed into the text area for further purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but it seems like you are essentially trying to roll your own version of a simple WYSIWYG editor, the goal being to have a textarea that allows users to see their input formatted as HTML in real-time.

In cases like this, my recommendation would be to make use of tried and true libraries out there, like [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/), rather than reinventing the wheel.

I've modified your code to use CKEditor below (as a starting point):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
    document.querySelector(`#postbody`).focus();
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#postbody'), {
            toolbar: ['bold', 'italic']
        })
        .then(editor => {
            document.querySelector(`#inputcountpost`).innerHTML = editor.getData().length;
            editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                document.querySelector(`#inputcountpost`).innerHTML = editor.getData().length;
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
})
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/28.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid row">
    <div class="col-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <!-- Card profile details -->
            <div class="card-header p-1">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-auto my-auto me-3">
                  <a href="/profile/admin">
                    <img class="rounded-circle m-2 ms-2" src="https://www.dia.org/sites/default/files/No_Img_Avail.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" height="40px" width="40px">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <a href="/profile/admin" class="row">admin</a>
                  <figcaption class="small row blockquote-footer text-muted font-monospace">
                    Add New Post
                    <figcaption class="col-auto ms-auto me-3 small text-end text-muted font-monospace">
                      <span id="inputcountpost">0</span>/200
                    </figcaption>
                  </figcaption>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Card body -->
            <div class="card-body" style="padding:0px">
              <textarea class="form-control blockquote mb-0 text-warp text-break" id="postbody" maxlength="200" style="resize:none;height:150px;box-shadow: none;border:0px none;position:relative;" autofocus>testing <b>innerhtml</b> activity</textarea>
            </div>

            <!-- Card Functionalities : bold, italics, etc and add post button-->
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
              <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-auto">

                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">

                </div>
                <div class="col-3 ms-auto">
                  <button class="btn form-control btn-primary" id="postsubmit" onclick="PostHandleForm(event)">
                      Add Post
                    </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

There are other naive solutions that do as you asked (hiding the textarea and showing the div with HTML formatted content), however, these do not perform well and suffer from poor UX.

Give a well established WYSIWYG library a try and I'm sure you'll find that it has many other benefits you probably haven't even considered yet. Of course, make sure to weigh the pros and cons for your use case with regards to increased bundle size from the addition of an external library.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it really helped me out and that is exactly what I was trying to create. but one more some help 

Is it possible to move the toolbar? like I want them in card footer where I created 2 empty col div's 

If so please help me out I am just a beginner to this

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful. I don't have too much experience with CKEditor, however, you can start by checking out the configuration options [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/configuration.html) and then diving deeper into the API to see what is possible.